# Multiplying lists of lists in netlogo

Tags: dictionary, netlogo

I have two different lists (`list1` and `list2`) such that:

```
list1  = [ [a1 a2 a2] 
           [b1 b2 b3] ]

list2  = [ [c1 c2 c3] 
           [d1 d2 d3] ]
```

I would like to multipliy the lists in the following way, to create a new `list3` such that.

```
list3 = [ [a1\*c1  a2\*c2  a3\*c3] 
          [b1\*d1  b2\*d2  b3\*d3]]
```

I could write a loop which iterates over each element, however, I think there might be a nicer way to use somehow the map function in netlogo.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is terribly elegant, but a double map will take care of an arbitrary number of lists of lists.

```
to test
  let list1 [ [2 6 12] [20 30 42] ]
  let list2 [ [1 2 3] [4 5 6] ]
  let list3 (map [[x1 x2] -> (map [[y1 y2] -> y1 / y2] x1 x2) ] list1 list2)
  show list3
end
```